# django app keeps migrating without taking effect [heroku]

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku

I have been trying to fix this for the past three days and I keep failing.

So, I have a simple app, that just has models.py and admin.py for now.
When I migrate locally, everything is totally fine, when I run createsuperuser, I can create a user that I can use to login into the admin dashboard.

However, when I do the same on heroku. It doesn't work..
[image: I ran makemigrations on heroku, then migrate]
The bad news is, those tables were never created, because this is what happens when I run migrate again:
[image: WHYY!]

I literally have no idea what's wrong with it, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are your creating migration files on heroku ? running `heroku run ./manage.py makemigrations` and then running `migrate`

Comment: Yes, look at the first picture, I did what you said.

Comment: AFAIK , you will need to push the migration files via git, then run migrations. It should work.

Comment: Can you please comment the command because I don't quite get what you mean..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the problem that dnit13 mentioned, the other issue is that you are using sqlite. That can not work on Heroku. You *must* use a proper db, which is provided by an add-on.

Comment: You were right, when I used Postgres instead, it worked. Had to learn it though and it was worth it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Create migration files locally `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Add these files to git and push to heroku. (Make sure migrations are not ignoreed in .gitignore)

```
git add .
git commit -m "migration files"
git push heroku master  # assuming your alias to be heroku
```

then migrate on heroku

```
heroku run ./manage.py migrate
```